# How to plot geom_crossbar with multiple points and lines for various y values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a line chart or dots or something else in a `geom_crossbar` chart for variables `etg` and `eac` in my data.

My current code is below:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    SNL = c("af1","af2","af3","af4","af5","af6"),
    etg = c(1408,1399,1382,1170,1026,869), 
    eac = c(1417,1447,1428,1415,1294,1422),
    prediction = c(1463,1463,1471,1387,1447,1431),
    lower = c(1296,1296,1304,1220,1280,1264),
    upper = c(1631,1631,1638,1554,1614,1598)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = SNL, y = prediction, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
    geom_crossbar(aes(color = SNL)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = etg), shape = 1) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = eac, group = 1))
```

Which creates:

[image: Plot]

How can I display an appropriate legend for `etg` and `eac`?

Comment: Is this close to what you want? `ggplot(df, aes(x = SNL, y = prediction, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(color = SNL)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = etg), shape = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = eac), shape = 2)`

Comment: great!  I love it how can i make the EAC a line or something  similar of a line

Comment: Instead of  `geom_point(aes(y = eac), shape = 2)`, you could do `geom_line(aes(y = eac, group = 1))`

Comment: Great!!  thanks for helping me.  How can i add legend for the line and the plot?  SNL already comes with a nice legend

Comment: I am not really sure of an elegant way to do this without hacking some of the aesthetics. I'll edit your question so that others might be able to help.